# How to use group price as primary price?

Tags: group-price

I set group price for group "Dealer". But I can't see this price in the frontend. I have enabled displaying in frontend area in attributes form, but I can't see this price still. Could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group price you have set up will display to the customers who belong to "Dealer" customer group. Most likely you are visiting product page not logged in or you are not assigned to "Dealer".

Comment: Hm, but I logged in as "Dealer". I can see only regular price. Not group price

Comment: OK it's problem with my template